# Query kubernetes pod (inside VM) from my local machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to deploy an api (wso2) on kube, and contact this API from my local machine.

Here is my setup :

- Windows WSL 2 (local machine)
- Ubuntu (VM)
- Minikube on the VM

Here is my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mi2-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mi2-test.fr
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mi2-httpservice
            port:
              number: 8290
  - host: mi2-test-https.fr
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mi2-httpservice
            port:
              number: 9201
  - host: mi2-test-http.fr
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mi2-httpservice
            port:
              number: 9164
```

[image: After the deployment :]

So it looks like my ingress.yaml have done it's work, but when I'm trying to reach http://mi2-test.fr:8290 => **CONNECTION REFUSED**

I've set up my hosts file too.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Edit : Here is my hosts file settings :

```
127.0.0.1 mi2-test.fr
127.0.0.1 mi2-test-http.fr
127.0.0.1 mi2-test-https.fr
```

And result of `kubectl get ingress mi2-ingress`:

[image: Results]

Comment: why you are hitting ? ` http://mi2-test.fr:8290` if your ingress mapped host, just try by hitting only domain no need to mention port from outside. if you are hitting this inside of any other pod to debug issue `http://mi2-test.fr:8290` there could be chances with service and deployment lable or selectors or container port in deployment.

Comment: I'm trying to get this from my windows machine. If you don't specify port, won't it go for the 80 by default ? (if http)

Comment: yes isn't your ingress controller listening on 80 & 443 ? and after SSL off-loading plain http request will be forwarded to respective service based on hostname match.

Comment: Yep, still connection refused sadly ...

Comment: did you tried port forward and debug? `kubectl forward svc/mi2-httpservice 8290:8290` after that hit `localhost:8290`

Comment: @cesar, sounds like your minikube is not function properly, you may have to [check](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) your installation.

Comment: It works with the forwarding ! 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please Cesar, could you share in details the port forward suggestion from Harsh?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above in the comments, You may give a try with port forward:

`kubectl forward svc/mi2-httpservice 8290:8290`

Afterwards test on `localhost:8290`